# Where can I find a list of TomEE 9.x / tomcat 10.0 provided jars?

Tags: dependencies, war, apache-tomee

I am using TomEE webprofile.  When building a WAR file for deployment, my POM includes "provided" dependencies. So, for example, the jakarta.platform is "provided".  But also, I see jackson (-core, -databind, -annotations etc.) dependencies are "provided".  It's not obvious if or when a dependency is "provided".

Where do I find a comprehensive list of dependencies that are provided by the server?

Comment: Check the /lib folder or take a look into the BOMs: https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/main/boms

Answer (score 1):

TomEE is providing BOMs, which contain this kind of information. You can find it for TomEE 10.x here:

- https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/main/boms/tomee-webprofile/pom.xml

For already released versions of TomEE, you find them via Maven:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomee.bom/tomee-webprofile/9.1.1

Comment: Splendid, thanks!